# How can I automatically set the core dump size on a single user?

Tags: memory, opensuse, ulimit, core-dump

I am running OpenSUSE. I usually open the console with an interactive non-login shell `bash`, and frequently use `tcsh` after logon. I am writing some `C` code, compiling with `gcc`, and I'd like to have the core dump files created whenever an executable fails.

I know I can select manually the core dump size to be unlimited, but I don't want to type

```
limits coredumpsize unlimited
```

in `tcsh` or

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

in the default shell `bash` every time I log on as my user.

Is there a way to set the core dump size automatically whenever I logon as user in `bash` and/or `tcsh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I may have solved the problem. Once I login to the UNIX machine, it redirects me to the `home` directory, according to the shell chosen, from the available ones on the system from the file `\etc\passwd` as follows:

```
alandella:x:1000:100:alandella:/home/alandella:/bin/bash
```

This explains the non-login interactive `bash` shell (konsole). The shell, let it be `bash` or `tcsh` runs, and the following files are read at login/logout:

```
~/.login  -> Executes cmds at login
~/.tcshrc ->               same as ~./bashrc in bash and ~./cshrc in csh
~/.logout ->               at logout
```

So, by adding the following lines to the `~/.tcshrc` and `~/.bashrc` files:

```
~/.bashrc -> ulimit -Sc X
~/.tcshrc -> limit coredumpsize X
```

where `X` is a value (kB) or `unlimited`, and it should do the trick.

Sometimes, it is told to also edit the `~/.profile` file. I did not edit it, even if MY `bash` shell sources it at login. *Why does it not make a difference? Because I always use a non-login shell, as I double-click konsole to open the terminal.* The `~/.profile` file is sourced at startup only in a login shell (usually `sh`, which I do not use). I have `bash` that looks at the following files in sequence:

```
.bash_profile -> .bash_login -> .profile
```

in MY case, the first two files do not exist, so `bash` sources `.profile` if I use a login shell.

**NOTE.** This operation must be done as root, and in order to make this trick work, the following conditions must/should be met:

1. That the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` sets suitable hard/soft limits for the user and root. If a hard limit of the core dump size of 2000 kB is imposed, then when we modify `~/.bashrc` with 3000 kB, the core dump size limit will continue to be 2000 kB. [Lookup  `limits.conf`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-limits.conf/).
2. That the files under `/etc/pam.d` contain the `session  required    pam_limits.so` line, in order to allow the `/etc/security/limits.conf` settings to take place.
3. That the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` contains `kernel.core_pattern = core.%e.%p`, this sets the format of the generated core files, where %e is the executable filename and %p is the pid.

Comment: Note: the `~/.bashrc`, `~/.cshrc` and `~/.tcshrc` are initialisation scripts which are read at each shell or subshell. If for example you run a shell script which make a loop running another subshell 1000 times, this initialisation script will be read 1000 times. The `ulimit` or `limit` you need, has to be called only once and so has to be called within `~/.profile` or `~/.login`.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I tried that, but whenever I delete the lines in ~/.bashrc or ~/.tcshrc and add the new limit setting in ~/.profile, the soft limit for the core sticks at 0 for some wizardry I cannot wrap my head around